# Load Data in Modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to load data into a modal popup.

In my Post model I have a title and a description.

I would like the title to appear in a table and when clicked the modal to appear with the description text inside.

(Below is the code for the table with an index and the post's title and a link that opens the modal.)

```
<% @posts.each_with_index do |post, index| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= index + 1 %></td>
      <td><%= post.title %></td>
      <td>Link-to-display-modal-goes-here</td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

I have a hidden div and I can make it appear/disappear by clicking a button.  I just do not know how to populate the div.

Below is the div that I would like to load the post's description.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">
  post's description goes here.
</div>
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your "link-to-display-modal-goes-here" with a link that invokes your own custom javascript method.  In this method, you can then set whatever data you want in your modal and then show it.

so, when you're generating your view, replace your current link to display modal with something like this:

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="javascript:openMyModal('<%= post.description %>')">Description</a></td>
```

then your javascript can be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    window.openMyModal = function (postDescription) {
      $('#myModal').text(postDescription);
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
      return false;
    }
  });
</script>
```

This is just an example, so you'll have to tweak it to do exactly what you want.  However, going this direction should work for you.

Comment: Hey I just woke up and tried this. It works perfectly, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the data-toggle to open modal, you can associate your source link to a click handler. I prefer to do this as to put this inline as csturts does, this better separates html and script. So you can have a link

```
<a class="btn btn-modal" data-desc="description">title</a>
```

and a script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn-modal').click( function() {
    $('#myModal').find('#myModal-div').html($(this).data('desc'));
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can populate the `div` with a call like this:

```
$('#my-modal-div').html('<span>Some HTML GOES HERE</span>')
```